# xCode 6 (beta 4) keep getting "The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use."

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite, xcode6

I keep getting the "The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use." when trying to run my app, this only happens about 20% of the time but once so far the only way to get around it is to restart my Mac.

Tried the following but doesn't help:

Cleaning my build folder 
Closing and re-opening xCode
Force close of simulator

I'm Using xCode 6 (beta 4)

Any Ideas for a solution that doesn't entail me restarting my Mac?
Thanks

Comment: quit the simulator and restart it... or the entire Xcode, if that does not help – but for me it was always enough to restart the simulator only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Simulator can't be launched because it is already in use.”

1. This messege will be shown only if there is another xcode project that has launched simulator and hasnt stopped it yet, and u try to run the simulator from another xcode project.
2. Ideally stopping the simulator from the respective project(PS. not closing the application from the simulator, clicking the STOP button) would do it, 
   But if it still is working like that, then Closing the simulator, or resetting the simulator contents.
3. If that still dsnt work, then as a last resort i would ask u to reinstall Xcode, as if this problem keeps going on, then ur downloaded file might be buggy.

P.S if u opt to re-download n install xcode please keep backup.

Hope it solves it. Although i want your problem to be solved by step 2.

Comment: Resetting the simulator contents works but not ideal due to it clear any cached data and doesn't solve the root cause of the issue. But a work-around none the less.

Answer (score 0):

This normally just happens when running an app (project) on the simulator and then trying to run another app while the simulator is open (and normally is still within the first app you launched and it can't quit automatically). As long as you keep running the same app you shouldn't get this error and as soon as you run another app just make sure you've closed the simulator before or at least left the previous app with the home button.

Comment: In my situation it was only the one application running, so far only resetting simulator contents or restarting my Mac seem to work. The route of the problem seems to be in xCode 6 (beta 4) or OS X (10.10).

Answer (score 0):

Just Restart Your Mac , It Will Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it without restarting. You just need to reset the content on ios simulator, exit xcode, and then to make sure that you've completely exited, right clicking on the xcode icon on your mac nav bar and click Quit. Open it back up and it should work.